# Multi-page posts do not get indexed by Google due to canonical URLs

Tags: wp-head

I've just noticed that on my paginated posts, only the main page gets indexed in Google. The paginated posts "post-title/2" and "post-title/3" for example, do not get indexed.

On closer inspection, it appears that Wordpress creates the same canonical URL for all pages in a paginated sequence. So, the canonical for page 2 is the same for page 1, etc. So when google crawls page 2+, the canonical directs them back to the first page.

Any clues how to go about resolving this to get a more intelligent canonical url on paginated posts and pages?

Comment: What is creating the canonical URL link? Last I checked WordPress does not do that by default.

Comment: WordPress, as of version 3.x? In order to remove it you have to include `remove_action('wp_head', 'rel_canonical')`

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: @N2Mystic The `rel_canonical` function was introduced in WordPress 2.9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to replace the default `rel_canonical` function to do this:

```
function wpse_84647_rel_canonical() {

    /* Only affect singular posts. Exit early if Yoast SEO is doing this for us */
    if ( ! is_singular() || class_exists( 'WPSEO_Frontend' ) )
        return;

    /* Get the post permalink */
    $post = get_queried_object();
    $link = trailingslashit( get_permalink( $post->ID ) );

    /* Get the number of pages the post is split into */
    $numpages = substr_count( $post->post_content, '<!--nextpage-->' ) + 1;

    /* Get the current pagination page number */
    $page = ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : 1 );

    /* Add the page number if the post is paginated */
    if ( $numpages && $page > 1 )
        $canonical = user_trailingslashit( $link . $page );
    else
        $canonical = get_permalink( $post->ID );

    /* Output the canonical link */
    printf ( "\n" . '<link rel="canonical" href="%s" />', $canonical );

    /* Add the adjacent rel links */
    if ( $page > 1 ) {
        remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0 );
        /* Link to the previous adjacent post */
        $prev = $page - 1;
        if ( $prev > 1 )
            printf ( "\n" . '<link rel="prev" href="%s" />', user_trailingslashit( $link . $prev ) );
        else
            printf ( "\n" . '<link rel="prev" href="%s" />', get_permalink( $post->ID ) );
    }
    if ( $page < $numpages ) {
        remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0 );
        /* Link to the next adjacent post */
        $next = $page + 1;
        printf ( "\n" . '<link rel="next" href="%s" />', user_trailingslashit( $link . $next ) );
    }
    print "\n";
}

remove_action( 'wp_head', 'rel_canonical' );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse_84647_rel_canonical', 9 );
```

This new function adds gets the paginated page from the URL and adds it to the canonical link. It will also add next and previous links to the adjacent pages so Google knows

Also, if you use Yoast's WordPress SEO plugin you will not need this snippet, as the plugin handles canonical links for you.

Comment: @bungeshea Can you please explain more about what your script does to resolve this issue? How is this any different to the default `canonical` print? And it appears to have a problem, it prints `\n` on the page rather than making a new line. I wrote a question about this here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87514/make-google-index-the-entire-post-if-it-is-separated-into-several-pages

Comment: I just tested this on a fresh install of WP 3.5.1 and I cannot see what it is doing different to the default WP function that adds `canonical` to the header. The href link is the same on all pages which is no different to the original function. Unless of course, I am missing something here? Or maybe there is a typo in your script?

Comment: @bungeshea Does this only take affect on Pages? If so, can you please demonstrate how to use it for Posts? I ran another test with your code and I can confirm that on Posts, the href link stays the same on every page (meaning that it does not function correctly).

Comment: I would also like to add that if you use the plugin: WordPress SEO by Yoast, you can use the filter: `wpseo_canonical`.

Comment: @ChristineCooper Sorry, my bad. I've updated my post with fully-revised working code that has been carefully tested. Thanks for pointing this out! :)

Comment: @MichaelEcklund Yes, you could, but WordPress SEO by Yoast already adds the pagination page to the canonical link for you

Comment: @bungeshea Thank you for the update, although this script remains incomplete as it is missing the `link rel="next"` and `rel="previous"`. Without them, Google will index each page of the post as a separate entry. I wrote more about this in my **Update 2**: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87514/make-google-index-the-entire-post-if-it-is-separated-into-several-pages Is there any chance that you can kindly add this feature to your script so that we can finally have a solution to this problem? Note that there should **not** be a rel="prev"/"next" if there isn't a page after/before it.

Comment: @bungeshea Can you please confirm if you will be updating your answer with the `link rel="next"/"prev"` solution that this issue requires? If you do not have the time, I can open a separate question to finally resolve this issue. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @ChristineCooper Yes, I am working on it. I am a bit busy at the moment, but it will be updated soon :)

Comment: @ChristineCooper Have a look at the updated code in my post. I've tested it thoroughly on WordPress 3.6-alpha. It will add the page number to the canonical links for posts with pagination, and prev/next links to pages before and after it (if they exist). For posts without pagination, the regular permalink will be the canonical link and no prev/next links will be added. Thanks again for pointing out the issues that I missed. Enjoy!

Comment: @bungeshea I tested this on WP 3.5.1 and I received this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'` it goes to the line `printf ( "\n" . '<link rel="canonical" href="%s" />', $canonical ) );`. I tried removing one of the `)` but it did not work. Do you know what the issue is? It is very likely a typo somewhere. Also, excellent update - I will certainly bring everyone that have been following my question to this answer once we get the script working.

Comment: `$GLOBALS['numpages']` is not set in `wp_head` in my tests.

Comment: @toscho and ChristineCooper, I have (hopefully) fixed all of the bugs in my updated code. Thanks for pointing them out! For some reason, error reporting was turned off in my development environment… weird…

Comment: @bungeshea Great update, I ran tests but a few issues still remain if you don't mind me detailing. Wordpress core already prints a `link rel='prev'/'next'` and the URLs goes to the previous/next published posts. So with your script, there are two instances of these, one which is yours using double quotation marks and one which is with single quotations. The solution would be to disable the core one **if** the post is multi-paged. The other issue is very minor, the `link rel` URL for the *first* page should ideally be `http://domain.com/post-url/` and not `http://domain.com/post-url/1`.

Comment: @ChristineCooper Ah, okay. They're more SEO tips then coding tips, and I wasn't really sure of how to handle them. Thanks for clearing that up, I'll update my code soon-ish

Comment: @bungeshea Cheers!

Comment: @ChristineCooper I've updated the code. It is working for you?