# Make Google index the entire post if it is separated into several pages

Tags: php, optimization, google-search, search-engines, google

While this is a question, it is as well a **serious warning** to publishers that separate their posts using `<!--nextpage-->`.

Bare with me. I run a highly trafficked multiple author platform that rank very high on search engines. While making SEO related improvements, I noticed that only the first page of an article that is separated into several pages is being indexed by Google. How did I notice this?

Because someone grabbed the content of the unindexed pages of an article and posted it in their own site. This resulted in them ranking higher than me on that particular keyword. Actually, let me rephrase that, my site's article is not even indexed beyond the first page.

My question is, how can I make the search engines index the whole article if it is separated into several pages? Ideally, a script that displays the full article **if** the visitor is a search engine (if that would not be harmful for SEO). Other suggestions are welcome.

On a side-note, if I was into Black Hat techniques, there would be a goldmine of content out there that I could exploit. *Think* about it.

And on a personal note, this issue should be addressed in a future update of Wordpress.

**Update**: A similar question that detailed how *Wordpress creates the same canonical URL for all pages in a paginated sequence* was asked [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84647/multi-page-posts-do-not-get-indexed-by-google-due-to-canonical-urls/), however the [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84647/multi-page-posts-do-not-get-indexed-by-google-due-to-canonical-urls/84711#84711) that was posted and marked as correct does not answer the question. That solution works for paged comments only, not paginated posts.

**Update 2**: According to [this](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html) blog post by Google, we can use `rel=”next”` and `rel=”prev”` to indicate the relation between pages. So for instance, this is what we should include in `<head>` on **page 2**:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://domain.com/article/2" />
<link rel="prev" href="http://domain.com/article/1" />
<link rel="next" href="http://domain.com/article/3" />
```

And there should not be a rel="prev" or "next" if there isn't a page after/before it.

Comment: Seems like you've found the answer. Care to format it as such and accepting it? I think a lot of people will benefit from this.

Comment: @tbuteler While I found the solution which is to add a unique Canonical URL on each paginated page **and** to include the `link rel="prev"/"next"` whenever necessary, I do not have a script for it written. However, toscho mentioned in the chat that he *may* have something. Watch this space for updates...

Comment: I've updated the code in [my answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/84711/19726) on the question you referred to. I have tested it, and it solves your problem. Good work on finding about this flaw!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem for a script solution is: `rel_canonical` does not offer any useful filter. So we have to replace that function:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'rel_canonical' );
add_action( 'wp_head', 't5_canonical_subpages' );
```

The next problem: `$GLOBALS['numpages']` is empty before `setup_postdata()`. We could call that function already here, but it might have side-effects.

Here is a solution that adds correct prev/next links too, and it prevents conflicting relations caused by `adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head`. We have too hook into `wp_head` not later than priority 9 to deactivate the latter hook.

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'rel_canonical' );
add_action(    'wp_head', 't5_canonical_subpages', 9 );

/**
 * Extend version of the native function rel_canonical()
 *
 * @wp-hook wp_head
 * @return  void
 */
function t5_canonical_subpages()
{
    if ( ! is_singular() )
        return;

    if ( ! $id = $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object_id() )
        return;

    $post = get_post( $id );
    setup_postdata( $post );

    # let WordPress do all the work
    if ( empty ( $GLOBALS['page'] ) )
        return rel_canonical();

    $permalink = get_permalink( $id );
    $canonical = t5_page_permalink( $permalink, $GLOBALS['page'] );
    echo "<link rel='canonical' href='$canonical' />";

    # next and prev links
    if ( 1 < $GLOBALS['page'] )
    {
        $prev = t5_page_permalink( $permalink, $GLOBALS['page'] - 1 );
        print "<link rel='prev' href='$prev' />";
    }

    if ( isset ( $GLOBALS['numpages'] ) && $GLOBALS['page'] < $GLOBALS['numpages'] )
    {
        $next = t5_page_permalink( $permalink, $GLOBALS['page'] + 1 );
        print "<link rel='next' href='$next' />";
    }

    # avoid conflicting pev/next links
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head' );
}

/**
 * Helper to get correct permalinks for sub-pages.
 *
 * @param  string $permalink
 * @param  int    $page
 * @return string
 */
function t5_page_permalink( $permalink, $page )
{
    if ( 1 == $page )
        return $permalink;

    # no pretty permalinks
    if ( '' === get_option( 'permalink_structure' ) )
        return add_query_arg( 'page', $page, $permalink );

    return $permalink . user_trailingslashit( $page, 'single_paged' );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the script. Do you have the time to add the `link rel="prev"/rel="next"` feature as noted in `Update 2` of my question.

Comment: That would require a `setup_postdata()` – something that should happen much later during page rendering.

Comment: Should I open a separate question for it even though the 'link rel' is required for this indexing issue to be resolved?

Comment: @ChristineCooper I have added that now. Not sure what side effects it might cause.

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a test and report back. Can you please tell me why you would make a note that it may have side effects? Is there anything in particular that I should be looking for?

Comment: There is probly a good reason for why that function is not called earlier. It will cause conflict if you are using `query_posts()` later (not recommended, but some plugins do it anyway) or if you are using a static front page with sub-pages.

Comment: Got it - is there any way around it if these conflicts occure (besides changing my theme setup)?

Comment: I have run tests and found the following issue. On the very first page of a multi-paged post, it does not print the `link rel` for the next page. However, both the canonical URL and the link rels works fine on all other pages.

Comment: did you have a chance to look at the issue that I noted above? Also, I ran further tests, particularly on pages where `query_posts()` is used and I did not notice any issues visually.

Comment: @ChristineCooper I moved the `setup_postdata()` part up, this could solve the issue with the missing `$page` variable. This is **untested**; maybe I find time this evening.

Comment: Works fine now. I will continue to perform tests today to see if it functions well. I have a question. I checked pages where `query_posts()` is being used and it loaded fine visually. You mentioned that there *may* be issues, if it loads fine visually, then am I safe to use it on those pages or is there a chance that it will misbehave in a way that I may miss it (issues with performance etc)...?

Comment: If `query_posts()` has been used to replace the main content the pagination will be wrong.

Comment: No `query_posts()` is being used on a widget for popular posts.

Comment: I left this a while to test and see how Google indexes the posts now and I am happy to confirm that this script works perfectly. Well done!

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI: Yoast's WordPress SEO plugin takes care of adding rel=prev and rel=next meta data to the `<head>` of pages. That guy (Yoast) thinks of everything!

Comment: -1 I am aware of this but I am not willing to install a massive SEO plugin just for one minor part of its features, neither should you unless you will be using everything it comes with.