# How to let crawlers search paginated comments?

Tags: pagination, seo, sitemap

With comment pagination, Google doesn't index the older pages and comments become essentially lost to searches.

Is there a way to let search engines crawl paginated comments, perhaps by generating a sitemap file that includes all paginated comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of why Google doesn't index paginated comments is because of an issue with the `canonical URL` in your header. You can learn more about the reason behind this in a comprehensive [question that I posted earlier](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87514/make-google-index-the-entire-post-if-it-is-separated-into-several-pages). There is an excellent solution posted there for paginated post pages.

Now, for Google to index comment pagination, [bungeshea](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/19726/bungeshea) posted an answer for a while ago when he (by accident) solved this when actually aiming to fix indexing for post pagination.

Luckily, I saved that code:

```
function comment_rel_canonical() {

    if ( ! is_singular() )
        return;

    global $wp_the_query;

    if ( ! $id = $wp_the_query->get_queried_object_id() )
        return;

    $link = get_permalink( $id );

    if ( $page = get_query_var('cpage') )
        $link = get_comments_pagenum_link( $page );

    if ( $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) )
        $link = add_query_arg( 'paged', get_query_var( 'paged' ), $link );

    printf ( '<link rel="canonical" href="%s" />\n', $link );
}

remove_action( 'wp_head', 'rel_canonical' );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'comment_rel_canonical' );
```

Comment: You can always link to a [single state of a post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/revisions/84711/2).