# How to remove Nextpage tag inside posts text depending of utm_campaign

Tags: posts, tags, content

Is it possible to remove "nextpage" tag inside posts text depending of utm_campaign ?

Depending of where my visitors are comming from, I want to remove the

```
<!--nextpage-->
```

of my post.

I am using this

```
if($_GET['utm_campaign']== 'nonextpagecampaign') {
```

directly in my template in order to display or not things depending of the campaign name but for the nextpage tag, it's not that easy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `the_post` hook to remove `<!--nextpage-->`. In this case:

```
add_action( 'the_post', 'campaign_remove_nextpage', 99);

function campaign_remove_nextpage ( $post ) {
    if ( ($_GET['utm_campaign']== 'nonextpagecampaign') && (false !== strpos( $post->post_content, '<!--nextpage-->' )) ) 
    {
        // Reset the global $pages:
        $GLOBALS['pages']     = [ $post->post_content ];

        // Reset the global $numpages:
        $GLOBALS['numpages']  = 0;

       // Reset the global $multipage:
        $GLOBALS['multipage'] = false;
    }
};
```

[Read more about this issue](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/183582/how-to-ignore-or-disable-nextpage-tag)

More in general, you may want to read [this warning](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87514/make-google-index-the-entire-post-if-it-is-separated-into-several-pages) about SEO effects of using `<!--nextpage-->`.

Answer (score 4):

We can use the `content_pagination`<sup>[codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/content_pagination/)</sup> filter to modify the paginated content without modifying the globals directly:

```
add_filter( 'content_pagination', function( $pages )
{
    // Target only the correct utm_campaign GET parameter 
    if( 'nonextpagecampaign' !== filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'utm_campaign', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) )
        return $pages;

    // Remove the content pagination, only if it's already paginated
    if( count( $pages ) > 1 )
        $pages = [ join( '', $pages ) ];

    return $pages;
} );
```

where we return an array with the combined content when the correct `utm_campaign` GET paramter is detected. Hopefully you can adjust this further to your needs.