# How to remove the post pagination (Next page tag) depending on type of traffic source: from utm_campain or non-utm_campain

Tags: filters, pagination

Let me try to explain my problem. I want to create the next traffic filter: if user comes from utm_camnpain source the post will be show with pagination, if from other source the post will be show in single page. I tried code from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/229556/how-to-remove-nextpage-tag-inside-posts-text-depending-of-utm-campaign/229569#229569?newreg=bbe0eea299c549e3bf5b97b1b3a4bc09) and put it exactly after`<?php`tag in single.php (Single post). 
Maybe, somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the decision:

```
add_action( 'the_post', 'campaign_remove_nextpage', 99);

function campaign_remove_nextpage ( $post ) {

if (($_GET['utm_campaign']== 'Facebook' ||  $_GET['utm_campaign']== 'Twitter') && (false !== strpos( $post->post_content, '<!--nextpage-->' )) ) 
{   
}
else  {
    $totalArticlesPages = substr_count($post->post_content, '<!--nextpage-->');
// Google: not paginated
// Direct: not paginated
// Camp: paginated

    // Reset the global $pages:
    $GLOBALS['pages']     = [ $post->post_content ];

    // Reset the global $numpages:
    $GLOBALS['numpages']  = 0;

   // Enable multipage
    $GLOBALS['multipage'] = false;
 }};
```